# How long are typical letters of recommendation for grad school admission?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

Is it bad if a letter of recommendation for graduate school is over 1 page, like 1.5 pages?

Answer (score 6):

An LOR is typically one to two pages.  If it was five pages, that would be odd.

Comment: Are letters 2 pages in size common in graduate school?

Comment: Yes, an LOR that stretches to a second page is quite common.

Comment: Yes, this is about right. Just guesstimating, I’d say a mean of 1.4 pages with an SD of 0.5 pages. Less than half a page is very rare. More than two pages is unusual but not terribly so.